# TimelineJs3 stuck at Loading, the error is the json objects passed in the initialization of the timeline

Tags: jquery, json, timeline.js

I'm building my TimeLine.js and passing the json into the new object instatiation, the problem is timeline is passing dataObject.json as an Url instead of a json object. Does any anyone know what is the problem or a work around?!

```
<!-- 1 -->
```

https://timeline.knightlab.com/docs/instantiate-a-timeline.html

```
<link title="timeline-styles" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/css/timeline.css">

<!-- 2 -->
<script src="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/js/timeline.js">     </script>

var dataObject ={  
   'title':{  
      'text':{  
         'headline':'Nr Processo: 007969031',
         'text':'',

      },
      'events':[  
         {  
            "startDate":{  
               "year":"1900",
               "month":"1",
               "day":"1"
            },
            "endDate":{  
               "year":"1900",
               "month":"1",
               "day":"1"
            },
            "text":{  
               "headline":"3358254",
               "text":""
            },
            "media":{  
               "media":"<iframe id=\"iframe871\" width=\"100%\"  scrolling=\"no\" onload=\"javascript:DCP_resizeIframe();\"  frameborder=\"0\" src=\"/Acidentes/ProcessoTimeLine.aspx?EpisodioId=1\" ></iframe>",
               "credit":"",
               "caption":""
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}; 

var options ={  
   width:'100%',
   height:'1500',
   timenav_position:'top',
   language:'en',
   start_at_end:false,
   start_at_slide:0,
   initial_zoom:0
}; 

 window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('Timeline','dataObject.json',options);
```

Comment: Please post the link or source to the library for Timeline JS that you're using.

Comment: It's updated added the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TimelineJS](https://timeline.knightlab.com/index.html) supports JSON input. See the link below.

https://timeline.knightlab.com/docs/instantiate-a-timeline.html
Under **Creating your own JSON**
For detailed documentation
https://timeline.knightlab.com/docs/json-format.html

Also sample JSON https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS3/blob/master/website/templates/examples/houston/timeline3.json

As your JSON was not correctly formed, it wasn't working even when passed as an object.

See the working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7k3uzp2x/

Or all in one code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link title="timeline-styles" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/css/timeline.css">
        <script src="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/js/timeline.js">     </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="Timeline"></div>
    <script>
        var dataObject =        {  
            "title":{  
                "text":{  
                    "headline":"Nr Processo: 007969031",
                    "text":""
                }
            },
            "events":[  
                {  
                    "start_date":{  
                        "year":"1900",
                        "month":"1",
                        "day":"1"
                    },
                    "end_date":{  
                        "year":"1900",
                        "month":"1",
                        "day":"1"
                    },
                    "text":{  
                        "headline":"3358254",
                        "text":""
                    },
                    "media":{  
                        "url":"<iframe id=\"iframe871\" width=\"100%\"  scrolling=\"no\" onload=\"javascript:DCP_resizeIframe();\"  frameborder=\"0\" src=\"/Acidentes/ProcessoTimeLine.aspx?EpisodioId=1\" ></iframe>",
                        "credit":"",
                        "caption":""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }; 

        var options ={  
           width:'100%',
           height:'1500',
           timenav_position:'top',
           language:'en',
           start_at_end:false,
           start_at_slide:0,
           initial_zoom:0
        }; 

         window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('Timeline',dataObject,options);
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```